# SvelteKit: unable to run build

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I want to create a build file for node and run it but I am facing errors on my local machine.

I've produced a build file using `npm run build`. Copied it to another directory with `package-lock.json` and installed them, and ran `npm run preview` to preview it but it is giving me this error:

[image]

However, when I run the same build inside my project directory, it works, but when I copy it out and paste the build folder in another directory then it gives me this error.

What is happening?